# Try to dynamically generate array Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to dynamically build an array (fe_components which I initialize as empty) depending on the given types - which come from config file in real life.

The array for each given type also comes from a config file.

To simplify my exam, I wrote all the vars in one play.

I iterate over the types and build up the name of the corresponding array, whose content I would like to tie together.

```
- hosts : all

  vars:

     # types and fe_components_XX come in real life from different config files
     types:
       - rs
       - gg


     fe_components_gg:
         - gg_frontend'

     fe_components_rs:
         - rs_frontend_1
         - rs_frontend_2
         - storybook

     # init empty array to dynamically fill in
     fe_components: []

  tasks:

   # This is what I want to get (written in a static statement)
   - debug: msg="{{ fe_components_rs + fe_components_gg }}"

   # My dynamic approach fails:
   # try to dynamically build up the array for given types
   - set_fact:
       my_dyn_var: >-
          {% for item in types -%}
             {% set varname = 'fe_components_' ~ item -%}
             {{  fe_components + varname  }}
          {% endfor -%}


   - name: test it
     debug:
          msg: " {{ my_dyn_var }}"
```

When I run it, my concatenation ends up in a **"can only concatenate list (not \"unicode\") to list"** message
.

```
fatal: [frank-lap]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% for item in types -%}\n   {% set varname = 'fe_components_' ~ item -%}\n   {{  fe_components + varname  }}\n{% endfor -%}): can only concatenate list (not \"unicode\") to list"}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following fulfills your requirements. Key points:

- Don't use lengthy jinja2 templates to assign vars when it is possible to do it with standard ansible loops, filters and modules
- No need to initialize empty vars, you can use the [`default` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables)
- When you construct a var name dynamically, you either have to use the [array notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use) or the [vars lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html) to get it.

Here we go:

```
---
- name: My test play
  hosts : localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
     types:
       - rs
       - gg
       - notexists

     fe_components_gg:
         - gg_frontend

     fe_components_rs:
         - rs_frontend_1
         - rs_frontend_2
         - storybook

  tasks:

    - name: Static demo of what we are looking for
      debug:
        msg: "{{ fe_components_rs + fe_components_gg }}"

    - name: Build my list dynamically from typed list
      vars:
        list_name: "fe_components_{{ item }}"
      set_fact:
        my_dyn_var : "{{ my_dyn_var | default([]) + lookup('vars', list_name, default=[]) }}"
      loop: "{{ types }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ list_name }}"

    - name: Show my dynamic var
      debug:
        var: my_dyn_var
```

And the result:

```
PLAY [My test play] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Static demo of what we are looking for] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "rs_frontend_1",
        "rs_frontend_2",
        "storybook",
        "gg_frontend"
    ]
}

TASK [Build my list dynamically from typed list] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_rs)
ok: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_gg)
ok: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_notexist)

TASK [Show my dynamic var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_dyn_var": [
        "rs_frontend_1",
        "rs_frontend_2",
        "storybook",
        "gg_frontend"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Cool, tnx @Zeitounator

Comment: @901Franco: I just rejected your edit on my answer. That one belongs to a comment or do an edit of your own  question. Please take some time to go through the help section and get familiar with how the site functions. Meanwhile, I got your problem and on my way to edit the answer to solve it. Please ad the info that some typed list might not be defined to your own question.

Comment: @901Franco: Answer edited with fix your issue (that you still have to add by editing your question and not my answer).

Answer (score 0):

It was really a problem with the ansible version which I just upgraded to V2.9.0 and now the output is like Zeitounator's.

I know my condition also works:

```
  - name: Build my list dynamically from typed list
      vars:
        list_name: "fe_components_{{ item }}"
      set_fact:
        my_dyn_var : "{{ my_dyn_var | default([]) + lookup('vars', list_name) }}"
      loop: "{{ types }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ list_name }}"
      when: vars[list_name] is defined


TASK [Build my list dynamically from typed list] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_rs)
ok: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_gg)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=fe_components_notexists)
```

Comment: Please read my comments below my answer and edit your question to add the necessary info (i.e. a type list might not be defined and you get an error in such situation), else no one will understand why this is actually a pertinent answer. Moreover, if an answer fixes your issue, you should accept it to let everyone no there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my first example I started with combining arrays for which the above solution (with lookup vars) works pretty good.
When continuing with my project, I need to combine subelements of typed dictionaries, too.

```
- name: My test play
  hosts : localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
     types:
       - rs
       - gg
       - notexists

     # backend
     be_components: {}
     solr_cores: {}

     backend_config_rs:
        be_components :
          rs-document:   { dbaccess: True,  version: latest,  mvn_id: rs-document }
          rs-attachments:{ dbaccess: True,  version: latest,  mvn_id: rs-attachments }
        cores:
          rs: { name: rs_core, dir:  /var/solr/data/jurisdict }       


     backend_config_gg:
        be_components :
          gg-document:   { dbaccess: True,  version: latest,  mvn_id: gg-document }
          gg-importer:   { dbaccess: True,  version: latest,  mvn_id: gg-importer }
        cores:
          rs: { name: gg_core, dir:  /var/solr/data/law }      

  tasks:

  # Static demo of what I currently do
  - name: "dyn-config | combine backend variables with RS backend config"
    set_fact: 
       be_components: "{{ be_components | combine ( backend_config_rs.be_components ) }}"
       solr_cores:    "{{ solr_cores | combine ( backend_config_rs.cores ) }}"
    when: "backend_config_rs is defined"

  - name: "dyn-config | combine backend variables with GG backend config"
    set_fact: 
       be_components: "{{ be_components | combine ( backend_config_gg.be_components ) }}"
       solr_cores:    "{{ solr_cores | combine ( backend_config_gg.cores ) }}"
    when: "backend_config_gg is defined"

  - debug: var=be_components
  - debug: var=solr_cores
```

But then I try to do it in a dynamic way, I found out the lookup vars access doesnt return subelements of dicts.

```
  - name: "try with lookup"
    vars:
        listname:   "backend_config_{{ item }}"    
    set_fact:
       be_components: "{{ be_components | combine (lookup('vars', listname.components)) }}"
    loop: "{{ types }}"
    loop_control:
        label: "{{ listname }}"       
    when: vars[listname] is defined
```

I got

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'components'\n
```

Is there a way to access subelements of dicts via lookup vars?